# Why does OpenApi generator name the class of service Api as "DefaultService" in Angular13

Tags: openapi-generator, angular13

I add OpenApi Generator in my angular project, but when i generate the Api with the command " **openapi-generator-cli generate -i ../openApi/src/main/resources/api.yml -g typescript-angular -o src/app/core/api/v1**", the name of Api service generted is **default.service.ts**, how can I change the name generated ?

api.yml :

```
openapi: 3.0.3
info:
  title: Test
  description: 
  version: 1.0.0
servers:
  - url: /api
paths:
  /tests:
    $ref: './controllers/test.yml#/tests'
```

test.yml

```
tests:
  get:
    operationId: loadTests
    responses:
      '200':
        description: 
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              type: array
              items:
                $ref: '../model/test.yml#/b'
```

script added to package.json :

```
"generate:api": "openapi-generator-cli generate -i ../openApi/src/main/resources/api.yml -g typescript-angular -o src/app/core/api/v1"
```

version of openApi :

```
"@openapitools/openapi-generator-cli": "^2.4.26",
```

[image of files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5piEn.png)

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this using *tags* in your operation object.

```
tests:
  get:
    tags:
    - testtag
    operationId: loadTests
    responses:
      '200':
        description: 
      ...
```

In the above example, you'd get *testtag.service.ts*. It is allowed to specify more than one tag - but be aware: for each tag there will be one .service.ts-file. You can but don't have to introduce these tags separately to add a description.
All paths that have no tag will end up in the default.service.ts-file.

To learn more about tags and operations, you should have a look at the [operation object chapter](https://swagger.io/specification/#operation-object) and/or the [tag object chapter](https://swagger.io/specification/#tag-object) of the specification